# useState doesn't update state passed in component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, use-state, react-usememo

The **SelectedColumn** value doesn't come in the **CustomHeader** component. However, **setSelectedColumn** works! Why ?
Also, I'm passing **CustomHeader** to constant **components** that use useMemo. Without useMemo CustomHeader doesn't work.

```
  const [selectedColumn, setSelectedColumn] = useState(null);
  console.log("selected Column Outside:", selectedColumn); // It works!

  const CustomHeader = (props) => {
    const colId = props.column.colId;

    console.log("selected Column In CustomHeader:", selectedColumn); // Doesn't work
    return (
      <div>
        <div style={{float: "left",  margin: "0 0 0 3px"}} onClick={() => setSelectedColumn(props.column.colId)}>{props.displayName}</div>
        { selectedColumn === colId ? <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faPlus} /> : null}
      </div>
    )
  }

  const components = useMemo(() => {
    return {
      agColumnHeader: CustomHeader
    }
  }, []);
```

UPDATE: If I use the useState hook inside the **CustomHeader** component, it adds a "+" sign to each column and does not remove from the previous one. Here is a picture:

[image]

Comment: Hello, the reason it adds the "+" sign to each column is because of this line `        { selectedColumn === colId ? <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faPlus} /> : null}`, you're essentially conditionally rendering against all the columns you have. If you want to specify it for the current selected column, you'd have to specifically target in the onClick event handler.

Comment: @AbdulrahmanAli I have target **props.column.colId** on **setSelectedColumn**. Or do you mean something else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After reading your comment, your issue is clearly about where you want to place your useState.

First of all, you should always place useState inside a component. But in your case, apparently what you're trying to achieve is that when you select a column, the other columns get deselected.

Therefore, you need to pass both  `selectedColumn` and `setSelectedColumn` as props to your component, and create the useState on the parent component.

Assuming all your `CustomHeader` components share the same parent component, in which my example I'll call `CustomHeadersParent`, you should do something like this:

```
// added mock headers to have a working example
const headers = [
  {
    displayName: "Game Name",
    column: {
      colId: 1,
    },
  },
  {
    displayName: "School",
    column: {
      colId: 2,
    },
  },
];

const CustomHeadersParent = (props) => {
  const [selectedColumn, setSelectedColumn] = useState(null);

  return headers.map((h) => (
    <CustomHeader
      column={h.column}
      displayName={h.displayName}
      setSelectedColumn={setSelectedColumn}
      selectedColumn={selectedColumn}
    />
  ));
};


const CustomHeader = (props) => {
  const colId = props.column.colId;

  return (
    <div>
      <div
        style={{ float: "left", margin: "0 0 0 3px" }}
        onClick={() => props.setSelectedColumn(props.column.colId)}
      >
        {props.displayName}
      </div>
      {props.selectedColumn === colId ? <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faPlus} /> : null}
    </div>
  );
};

const components = useMemo(() => {
  return {
    agColumnHeader: CustomHeader,
  };
}, []);
```

Answer (score 3):

You should use hooks inside your component

```
  const CustomHeader = (props) => {
    const colId = props.column.colId;

    const [selectedColumn, setSelectedColumn] = useState(null); 

    console.log("selected Column In CustomHeader:", selectedColumn); // Should work
    return (
      <div>
        <div style={{float: "left",  margin: "0 0 0 3px"}} onClick={() => setSelectedColumn(props.column.colId)}>{props.displayName}</div>
        { selectedColumn === colId ? <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faPlus} /> : null}
      </div>
    )
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. If I use the useState hook inside the CustomHeader component, it adds a "+" sign to each column and does not remove from the previous one. I updated the post.